# Export georeferenced image into Google Earth

Tags: qgis, google-earth, export, image

I have created a georeferenced image as instructed in this fine tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-georeferencing-topo-sheets.html

Now I would like to get this image into Google Earth, as an Image Overlay or such. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on how you want to have it display.  If you want to show more detail as you zoom in (kind of like the maps from the Rumsey Map Collection do on Google Earth-- I believe that Google calls it a SuperOverlay), I'd recommend using something like MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.org/), which uses GDAL to split your image into tiles of different sizes and then will create a kml file with those tiles.

If you just want a plain, barebones overlay, I think that MapTiler can do that also.  Just set the minimum and maximum zoom level to 0, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Superovelay instructions are provides at https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster

Answer (score 1):

Also there is a plugin called [CustomGarminMap](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/garmincustommap) for exporting your QGIS canvas to .kmz format that is used both on Google Earth and Garmin devices.